# Do ALUs tend to do operations in parallel even if they are not selected by the machine instruction?

Tags: cpu

I was playing nandgame.com and noticed that the arithmetic unit of the ALU was doing both the add and subtract operation in parallel, but only asks for one operation per instruction. This to me seemed like it wasted resources, and I was interested in if this was a normal design-pattern in ALUs/CPUs. My question is, broadly, is it?

[image]

I then looked at some other example ALUs, to get a better understanding. First I looked at this one from learnabout-electronics.org ([link](https://www.learnabout-electronics.org//Digital/dig58.php)). It uses a different design, that does not do unrequested operations in parallel with the requested one. It does this with multiplexers as can be seen below. The subtraction for example is done by inverting B at MUX3.

I at the moment prefer something like that where it does not waste resources. But I want to learn more.

[image]

I then looked at this 2-bit ALU from wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/ALU. It is similar to the one from nandgame.com, in that it does unrequested operations in parallel with the requested one, and then discards the unrequested ones (but after having computer them. )

> *"Notice that all the operations are performed in parallel, and the
> select signal ("OP") is used to determine which result to pass on to
> the rest of the datapath. "*

[image]

I also looked at this 1-bit ALU that also does it all in parallel. Since I am not very knowledgeable, I cannot know if this is just common in simple concept designs (like nandgame.com example), or if it is also common in real advanced ALUs in actual computers. This is why I ask here, since there are experts here.

[image]

I then looked at the 6502, and it seems to also do many operations in parallel, and select only one for the output ([source](https://www.righto.com/2013/09/the-z-80-has-4-bit-alu-heres-how-it.html)).

> *"...the 6502's ALU, which uses simple gates to compute the AND, OR, SUM, and XOR in parallel, and then selects the desired result with
> pass transistors. "*

And the 6502 was contrasted to the 8085 [here](https://www.righto.com/2013/01/inside-alu-of-8085-microprocessor.html), and it does not seem to do operations in parallel.

> *"The 6502's ALU uses fairly straightforward circuits to generate the SUM, AND, XOR, OR, and SHIFT values in parallel, and then uses a
> simple pass-transistor multiplexor to pick the desired operation. This
> is in contrast to the 8085 ALU, which generates only the desired
> value. "*

Having looked at a few different ALUs for this question, I now solved the nandgame level with a design similar to the one on learnabout-electronics.org. It resolved the issue I originally had, but since I discovered real world ALUs like the one in 6502 does "wasted" operations in parallel, I still wonder about it and what the design-trends are.

[image]

Comment: It's very hard to find information about this because CPU design are usually proprietary. However the [Intel 8008](http://www.righto.com/2017/02/reverse-engineering-surprisingly.html) does not do this. In fact it uses the full adder addition circuit to also compute xor, and etc. by using the gates contained *within* the full adders. Note that modern CPU designs are crazy optimized by circuit minimization and layouting algorithms.

Comment: There are no "wasted resources". The hardware is there, using it or not does not make a difference. The rationale of CPU designers is to activate as much of the available circuitry to perform parallel computation and minimize the latency. Sometimes, this is even done in a speculative way, i.e. by performing some  operation before you know if the result will be needed or not.

Comment: (Using or not using parts of hardware *may* impact energy consumption.)

Comment: Thanks @plshelp for pointing out the issue with proprietary hardware. I read a bit about the intel 8008 too yesterday on Ken Schirrif's blog but did not manage to get if it was doing "wasted" operations in parallel or not, so thanks for pointing that out too. Yes I can imagine modern CPUs are different from the old ones, my level at the moment is that I am just starting to understand how a machine instruction actually orders the CPU to do specific things.

Comment: @YvesDaoust For the record I am very much a beginner, and this is why I reach out to this forum because people here are much more knowledgeable than me. My own thought on that it "wasted" resources is, like @ greybeard points out, the electricity usage. I was just imagining that a CPU "shuttled" instructions to different processes, not that it sent it to many processes at the same time but then only extracted the result from one. Since I was surprised by this, I wanted to know more about it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am specifically interested in the design rationale. What are the pros and what are the cons. And what are common design choices in the real world (I assume nandgame.com might not be real-world-like but a very simplified design for educational purposes. )

Comment: @YvesDaoust Also thanks for pointing out the use of "speculative" computations to save time, and parallel ("wasted") operations to minimize latency. I can see it being very important in CPU design. But I do not feel like this was the reason the 6502 ALU for example did "wasted" operations in parallel.

Comment: It depends heavily on the design of the ALU.

Comment: @user253751 Yes I realize that. Have studied different ALU designs in the past days since asking this question (mostly those on Ken Shirriff's blog), and I think I have understood why some designs do the "wasted operations in parallel" design. The gates necessary to avoid that and "silence" unused operations, are in themselves using a lot of electricity, and then also space, and money. I'm guessing that was main reason, but will learn more as I study more old ALU designs.